# Multiple File Uploads on Freeform not working

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace, forms

I had the following form working until I added file upload:

```
<h3>Submission Form</h3>

{exp:freeform:form
    collection="remnants"
    required="name|article_title|article_tagline|article"
    return="submit/submitted"
    file_upload="blog_user"
}

<p>Name: <input type="text" name="first_name" /></p>
<p>Email: <input type="text" name="email" /></p>
<p>Article Title: <input type="text" name="article_title" /></p>
<p>Article Tagline: <input type="text" name="article_tagline" /></p>
<p>Article:<br /><textarea name="article"></textarea></p>
<p>Attach a File: <input type="file" name="article_image" /></p>

<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></p>

{/exp:freeform:form}
```

I keep getting the following error:
Article Image: The upload path does not appear to be valid.

I've allowed for up to 10 images but only one input is showing. I'm wondering if I didn't probably create the input field?

Comment: Search for freeform multiple uploads and you'll find the answer, in thus very site. I'm using the app so cant copy/paste link

Comment: Thanks I actually had been looking around but all the answers I came to were slightly off -- about displaying the entries and not about the initial import.

Answer (score 1):

First, try changing

```
<input type="file" name="article_image" />
```

to

```
<input type="file" name="article_image[]" />
```

(Note the brackets: `[]`)

Alternatively, you can use `{freeform:field:article_image}`, which will generate the file field for you. You can then add the `show="10"` parameter to display 10 file upload fields. This is described in the documentation for the File Upload Field: http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/default_fieldtypes/#fileupload_show

**Note**: Instead of using `show="10"`, you can set the number of file fields from the CP in the Freeform module, when editing the file upload field settings. Look under **Allowed upload count**.

Comment: The alternative method even without the parameter works great. All ten are currently displayed. However, I am still getting the following error regarding the field once I hit submit: Article Image: The upload path does not appear to be valid.

Comment: There has to be issue with your upload field path. Can you confirm it was working prior to upgrade and can you also confirm if you use the backend you can upload a file to the directory in question. I jad issues recemtly with am upload path requiring a trailing '/' to make it valid

Comment: Interesting. This seems to have something to do with it. I removed the old paths and recreated new ones to ensure that they were ok. I can now upload directly into the file manager however using my form I now get the same error plus: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: server_path

Filename: default_fields/freeform_ft.file_upload.php

Line Number: 926

Comment: Make sure you have the correct file upload directory selected for your Freeform field. Re-save the field settings for good measure. Make sure the upload directory's path and URL are accurate in EE. Try to use absolute paths/URLs if necessary, to be sure the upload folder is set up correctly. Lastly, try setting your upload directory permissions to 777.